# JIT-Compiled Resources in Razor Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

We are currently reworking a WebForms based application to a MVC3/Razor system, and have hit a minor issue.

In our current solution, we have a large number of resources held within an external CMS that are compiled into our .aspx pages via a GlobalResource handler; this means that the hit on the CMS is low, and that the resources are only ever needed to be collected once for each individual page.

We can't seem to find any mechanism within Razor/MVC3 that would allow us to do the same thing - any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you are using an HttpHandler to serve up a bundle of resources. There's no reason that code can't continue to work in MVC3 as-is.  If you're doing something else, I'll need a little more clarification :). What's the underlying goal? To reduce the number of Http Requests per page?

Comment: The idea is to get string resources that are external to the application (text labels, HTML markup fragments etc.) and to have them 'baked' into views so that the external resource container (a CMS system for example) is only accessed once.

Comment: I've managed to sort out what I was after by providing a custom `RazorBuildProvider`; I'll try to write up the approach as an answer shortly